# How do I install PHP cURL on Linux Debian?

Tags: php, linux, curl

How do I install PHP cURL on Linux Debian? 
I tried the following code and got the error below

```
apt-get update
apt-get install curl libcurl3 php5-curl
```

Error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://zm.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Something wicked happened resolving 'zm.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://zm.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Something wicked happened resolving 'zm.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://zm.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en_US  Something wicked happened resolving 'zm.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://zm.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'zm.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://zm.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US  Something wicked happened resolving 'zm.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://zm.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'zm.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://zm.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US  Something wicked happened resolving 'zm.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://zm.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/restricted/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'zm.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://zm.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en_US  Something wicked happened resolving 'zm.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://zm.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/universe/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'zm.archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I resolved this issue. My Linux box was unable to browse and resolve hosts names.
After adding appropriate roots, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 45):

Type in console as root:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install php5-curl
```

or with sudo:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

Sorry I missread.

1st, check your DNS config and if you can ping any host at all,

```
ping google.com
ping zm.archive.ubuntu.com
```

If it does not work, check `/etc/resolv.conf` or `/etc/network/resolv.conf`, if not, change your apt-source to a different one.

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

Mirrors: http://www.debian.org/mirror/list

You should not use Ubuntu sources on Debian and vice versa.

Comment: I am able to ping the ip address of the ubuntu site, but it seems my webserver cant resolve the hostname

Comment: Ask your server provider for the dns settings used in `/etc/resolv.conf`, if you are using it in your private LAN, the DNS server is probably the same as the router and you put into this file like: `nameserver 192.168.1.1`

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an article on topis how to [manually install curl on debian linu][1]x.

[1]: http://www.jasom.net/how-to-install-curl-command-manually-on-debian-linux. This is its shortcut:

1. cd /usr/local/src
2. wget http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.36.0.tar.gz
3. tar -xvzf curl-7.36.0.tar.gz
4. rm *.gz
5. cd curl-7.6.0
6. ./configure
7. make
8. make install

And restart Apache. If you will have an error during point 6, try to run **apt-get install build-essential**.

Comment: Thanks for the succinct info. Update on step 2, latest version is now: http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.43.0.tar.gz

Comment: I ended up having issues with this approach because it didn't update libcurl to the latest version. I'll enter another answer with info on what I ended up doing...

Answer (score 2):

Whatever approach you take, make sure in the end that you have an updated version of curl and libcurl. You can do `curl --version` and see the versions.

Here's what I did to get the latest curl version installed in Ubuntu:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu wily main"`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install curl`